# Instant calculation without clicking the equal button and using more than one oper

Tags: java, android, calculator

this is my first question here
i am writing an android calculator application but i have few problems 
i am trying to make a feature in which once any operation button is clicked (+ , - / , *) the calculator supposed to show the result instantly instead of clicked equal button and on the same time you can do more than one operation , i succsed making it work for only one operation (+) but i can't get it to work with the other operations

i made it numbers button-wise
here is the code for number 3 button , maddition and msubstract are the buttons for the plus on click listener

```
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edt1.setText(edt1.getText() + "3");
                tv.setText(tv.getText() + "3");
                float z = Float.parseFloat(edt1.getText().toString());
                int i = 0;
                if (mAddition) {
                    String s = tv.getText().toString();
                    String x = "";
                    while (i < s.length()) {
                        if (s.charAt(i) != '+') {
                            x = x + s.charAt(i) + "";
                        } else {
                            float m = Float.parseFloat(x);
                            z = z + m;
                            x = "";


                        }
                        i++;


                    }
                    tvz.setText(z + "");
                    xAdd = false;

                }
                if (mSubtract) {
                    String s = tv.getText().toString();
                    String x = "";
                    while (i < s.length()) {
                        if (s.charAt(i) != '-') {
                            x = x + s.charAt(i) + "";
                        } else {
                            if (isDouble(x)){
                                float m = Float.parseFloat(x);
                                z = z - m;
                                x = "";
                            }


                        }
                        i++;


                    }
                    tvz.setText(z + "");
                    xSub = false;

                }
                }


        });
```

Additon on click listener

```
  buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt1.getText().toString())) {
                    return;
                }


                String str = edt1.getText().toString();


                if (isDouble(str)) {

                    if (edt1 == null) {
                        edt1.setText("");
                    } else {
                        mValueOne = Float.parseFloat(edt1.getText() + "");
                        tv.setText(tv.getText() + "+");
                        mAddition = true;
                        edt1.setText(null);

                    }

                } else return;
            }
        });
```

here is my source code 
https://pastebin.com/7QaDvx9D

error log cat 
05-27 12:33:55.565 24916-24921/ispam.mark_06 I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=17KB, data=24KB
05-27 12:33:55.565 24916-24921/ispam.mark_06 I/art: After code cache collection, code=17KB, data=24KB
05-27 12:33:55.565 24916-24921/ispam.mark_06 I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
05-27 12:33:56.931 24916-24916/ispam.mark_06 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-27 12:33:56.931 24916-24916/ispam.mark_06 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-27 12:33:57.375 24916-24916/ispam.mark_06 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-27 12:33:57.375 24916-24916/ispam.mark_06 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-27 12:33:58.948 24916-24916/ispam.mark_06 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-27 12:33:58.949 24916-24916/ispam.mark_06 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-27 12:33:59.931 24916-24916/ispam.mark_06 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-27 12:33:59.933 24916-24916/ispam.mark_06 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: ispam.mark_06, PID: 24916
                                                               java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3-3-3"
                                                                   at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
                                                                   at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:459)
                                                                   at ispam.mark_06.Calculator$4.onClick(Calculator.java:182)
                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5685)
                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22481)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

any help thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the error i understnad the cause to be that  your code is trying to parse the string "3-3-3" into float value, and hence the error.
To avoid this error you can clear the edit text after the answer has been calculated and shown i.e. do tv.setText(""); after you have shown the result so that the old operators still dnt get appended to the edittext text.

Comment: thanks sorry for late reply , i guess i think i am going to stick with Third party parsers thanks anyway